# How to open Pdf files in grid-view into a div grammatically

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I want to open a PDF file into a iframe or jframe. I can open this file having no problems.

```
<iframe src = "Pdf/SiteAnalytics.pdf" width = "100%" height ="800px" > </iframe>
```

This code can easily open the file into a iframe. But I have a dropdownlist. This dropdown list contains a list of PDF files. I want to open the PDF file which one is selected from the dropdownlist. How could it be done? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding runat="server" directive and access the iframe control from code-behind

```
<iframe id="myPDFiFrame" runat="server" width = "100%" height ="800px" />
```

And code-behind

```
this.myPDFiFrame.Attributes["src"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: thnx for your answer. but ur this.myPDFiFrame.Attributes["src"] is not working. Here myPDFiFrame is showing error